# How to forbid to press "next" button until all of inputs are updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, synchronization

I've got 30+ inputs on a single page. Each input has a callback on `ng-blur` (focus loss) which calls a remote API through `$http` AngularJS service. Each api request is running asynchronously in parallel. User may edit an input several times. Each time the `ng-blur` event is fired the data is sent to the server.

I also have the "next" button at the bottom of the page which user presses when he/she is done editing the inputs on a page. How to forbid user to press the "next" button until each of api PUT promises is finished? And what to do if some of HTTP requests failed because of 500 on server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by implementing some semaphore-like solution. Initially the semaphore counter is zero. I increment the counter every time the the promise is created and decrement it every time the promise resolves or rejects (in `.finally()`). Whenever the counter is zero the "next" button is available for user.

Answer (score 2):

Use a flag `finished` in the component.

In the view =>

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!finished">Add</button>
```

In the component =>

```
public finished = false;
```

In side the Promise =>

```
   let promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
   let promise2 = 42;
   let promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
    });

Promise.all([Promise1,Promise2,....]).then((...)=> {
  finished =true; // your button will be enabled!!
})
```

You can learn more from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

OR

You can use flag for each and every promise =>

```
public promiseF1 = false;
public promiseF2 = false;
public promiseF3 = false;
etc...
```

For each and every call, at the start make it `false` and when the call end make it `true`.

So the html will look like this =>

```
<button type="submit"[disabled]="!promiseF1 && !promiseF2 && !promiseF3 && etc...">
 Add
</button>
```

Comment: I've got multiple promises and I need a way to synchronize them, that's the problem

Comment: Use Promise.all()  :)

Comment: Then how to accumulate all the promises that may occur during the page edit? Simply adding them to the array will cause a memory leak

Comment: I need more data to go on , maybe give us sample code example?? . Although Promise.all()  will run all of the  Promises async.

Comment: I've edited the question. Sorry, can't reproduce the example, it's to big.

Comment: Ok i have made a edit , its a long shot but i have so little to go on

Comment: My current implementation is that one input may create several promises and it creates them dynamically. Number of currently ongoing promises is dynamic. May be that's the architectural flaw... What do you think?

Comment: If all those dynamic promises execute once you can use a promise.all(array), and  dynamically insert promises to array when its created, if not make input as a separate component and create a EventEmitter to listen when the promise is done

Answer (score 0):

Put "required" input parameter in each of the input fields, this way you can make sure that all the response from different promises are getting filled before submit button gets active.

And then check for form validity on submit button.

```
<form  #form="ngForm">
    //Your input fields with required paramets

  <button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">Next</button>

</form>
```

Comment: All the fields may be valid and then user may suddenly decide to edit something on some of them very fast. In that case validity is not a solution.

Comment: @JerrySmith the validation would fail. The user cannot be faster than the computer :)

Comment: @JerrySmith The picture isn't clear enough, it would be easier if you could reproduce your problem. As mentioned by Gaurav_soni also I think playing out with validations would definitely solve your problem.